# Recursive use of make for LaTeX

Tags: makefile

I am using a Makefile to handle building a LaTeX document. I have two directories `./tikz` and `./feyn` that contain `.tex` files and Makefiles to compile them. They produce figures which I then include in the main document. I am using the following Makefile to compile the main document:

```
.PHONY : tikz feyn

main.pdf : main.tex feyn tikz
    pdflatex main.tex

tikz :
    $(MAKE) -C tikz

feyn :
    $(MAKE) -C feyn
```

The problem is that even if `main.pdf` is up-to-date, running `make` will execute its rule anyways since phony targets are never up-tp-date. However, if I do not declare `tikz` and `feyn` as phony, their rules will not get executed. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, what do you want to do in the directories `feyn` and `tikz`. I guess that in `tikz` you want to generate some PDFs. Simply use an actual file as dependency. E.g.,

```
main.pdf : main.tex feyn tikz
    pdflatex main.tex

tikz : tikz/somefile.pdf

tikz/somefile.pdf:
    $(MAKE) -C tikz

# etc.
```

An alternative is to decouple `main.pdf` from your phony targets by using order targets:

```
.PHONY : tikz feyn

main.pdf : main.tex | feyn tikz
   pdflatex main.tex

tikz :
   $(MAKE) -C tikz

feyn :
   $(MAKE) -C feyn 

all: feyn tikz main.pdf
```

Comment: All I am doing in the `feyn` and `tikz` directories is running `pdflatex` to produce a pdf. This solution doesn't entirely work. Since `main.pdf` depends only on the .pdf files, then they will indeed get built if they do not exist, but they will not be rebuilt if I make changes to their `.tex` files. Perhaps, switch the dependency to the `.tex` files instead?

Comment: It is not about existence, but change date. However, you are right with the general idea. If you don't delete the pdf after processing, you should construct a dependency to files that changes. In general, recursive make is not regarded as a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run pdflatex in the subdirectories. Instead run latexmk in those diectories. The call to latexmk always happens (since the targets are phony), but latexmk will bail if nothing needs to be done for a subdirectory.

And then also probably use latexmk for the top-level target too.